# Select a row on condition plus the next one

Tags: r

This is my example code:

```
pdata <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:5, each = 5),
  time = rep(2016:2020, times = 5),
  value = c(c(1,1,1,0,1), c(1,1,0,1,1), c(1,1,1,0,1), c(1,1,1,1,1), c(1,0,1,1,1))
)
```

How can I select all the rows with a 0 plus just the one next row (regardless of the value)?
I'd like to have an outcome like that:

```
# A tibble: 25 × 4
      id     time    value   condition
    <int>   <int>    <dbl>    <lgl>    
 1     1    2016       1       TRUE    
 2     1    2017       1       TRUE    
 3     1    2018       1       TRUE    
 4     1    2019       0       FALSE     
 5     1    2020       1       FALSE     
 6     2    2016       1       TRUE    
 7     2    2017       1       TRUE    
 8     2    2018       0       FALSE     
 9     2    2019       1       FALSE     
10     2    2020       1       TRUE    
# … with 15 more rows
```

Importantly, I want to be able to filter both rows (0 and the next one) out of my data set afterwards.
I've tried the `mutate()` function and a for loop, but nothing has worked, neither have other posts on stackoverflow. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `filter()` and `lag()` from the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

pdata %>%
  filter(value == 0 | lag(value) == 0)
```